# Parse external site and get variables

Tags: php

I have a link to a web pages from which i want to get the text. As example the page contains somewhere this lines:

```
<span property="v:latitude" content="-31.941283"></span><span property="v:longitude" content="115.85838"></span>
```

I neeв to get -31.941283 and 115.85838 from there. What is the best and fustest way to do it in PHP?

So far I got something like this:

```
public function _getLocationFromSite($pSiteHTML){
    if ( !$pSiteHTML ){
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!preg_match('/(<span property="v:latitude" content="[^"]+">)/', $pSiteHTML, $matchelat)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!preg_match('/(<span property="v:longitude" content="[^"]+">)/', $pSiteHTML, $matchelon)) {
        return FALSE; 
    }

    $location['lat'] = (float)( $matchelat);
    $location['lon'] = (float)($matchelon);

    return $location;
}
```

It doesnt work...any ideas?

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows you have an unterminated string in your second `preg_match`.  Though even after fixing that, you're probably better off using a DOM parser instead of regular expressions.

Comment: My mistake, bad copy paste, but still it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

The regex is correct but your captures are wrong.

```
function _getLocationFromSite($pSiteHTML){
    if ( !$pSiteHTML ){
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!preg_match('/<span property="v:latitude" content="([^"]+)">/', $pSiteHTML, $matchelat)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!preg_match('/<span property="v:longitude" content="([^"]+)">/', $pSiteHTML, $matchelon)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $location['lat'] = (float)($matchelat[1]);
    $location['lon'] = (float)($matchelon[1]);

    return $location;
}
```

There is also room for improvements, that is the code can be further reduced. Here is an example:

```
<?php
function _getLocationFromSite($html) {
    preg_match_all('/<span property="v:(.*?)" content="(.*?)">/', $html, $matches);
    return array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}
var_dump(_getLocationFromSite(null));
var_dump(_getLocationFromSite(''));
var_dump(_getLocationFromSite('<span property="v:latitude" content="-31.941283"></span><span property="v:longitude" content="115.85838"></span>'));
?>
```

And here is its result:

```
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(2) {
  ["latitude"]=>
  string(10) "-31.941283"
  ["longitude"]=>
  string(9) "115.85838"
}
```

Comment: Nice code!) but it always returns 0's...can it be possibly be because the page i put in $html is redirected to another one with spans i mentioned...? Sorry for stupid questions(

Comment: I think it is because the reduced version returns `'latitude'` and `'longitude'` as keys while you are expecting `'lat'` and `'lon'`.

Comment: No, seems like works ok if you give direct page url, but when redirecting from url it returns 0. The urls we are passing to veriable is like this: http://pdt.tradedoubler.com/click?a(2427615)p(34444)prod(711249875)ttid(5)url(http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hostelbookers.com%2Fhostels%2Findonesia%2Fdenpasar%2F49032%2F%3Faffiliate%3Dtradedoubler) and the actual url is another...

Comment: No, actually it doesnt work even if adress is correct(

Comment: It returns $matches[1] as Array...?!

Comment: `$matches[1]` is an array. I tried the code above and it is working. I'll post the full test case.

Comment: If var_dump(_getLocationFromSite('http://pdt.tradedoubler.com/click?a(2427615)p(34444)prod(711249875)ttid(5)url(http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hostelbookers.com%2Fhostels%2Findonesia%2Fdenpasar%2F49032%2F%3Faffiliate%3Dtradedoubler)'));

It returns errors...

Comment: It should not return error: it returns (correctly) an emtpy array. Your original function (and consequently mine one) was about parsing strings, not fetching html from remote addresses.

Comment: Yes, got you. Thank you, for sure it works with string, but the question was about parsing page content from url...maybe i described the question badly...but thank you anyway!